# Show logged-in user upvoted answer at the top

Tags: feature-request, answers, upvotes, users

Users visit Stack Overflow looking for, from a simple Linux command, to complete solution of their programming problems and many more things.

Many time users will come and copy the command (solution) (which serve their purpose) and go back into their busy life. It is normal for most users to forget it (instantly or over time). Again when they encounter the same problem and land on the Stack Overflow for the same command or answer. It happens that they need to (dig) read couple of answers before finding/reaching the same previous command (answer).

The registered and regular users always have tendency to up-vote the answer which was helpful to them.

My suggestion (request) is, would it be a good idea to show a answer at top (at first position) which is up-voted by the user (currently logged-in user).

I believe it will also encourage users to always up-vote the answer which helped them, so that they can find the answer at top only.

Comment: You could just scroll to see if you've upvoted any answers, the orange arrow is a bit of a giveaway.

Comment: If you're looking for "a simple Linux command" you'd better not be asking on SO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been asked [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278810/add-sort-by-my-votes) on Meta Stack Exchange, and somebody wrote a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/upvote-first-for-stackove/jafbgebfjkfejghbdeohaadmfghkmjlo) which lets you do exactly this. While I see the occasional usefulness of this feature, I feel that SE developer time is better spent elsewhere.